# how to upgrade dojo version of Maximo Anywhere project

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2.1 is shipped with the dojo version 1.7.8
I wanted to use some of the features available in dojo 1.10.x.
I tried replacing the `www` directory with new version of the dojo.
But it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we use 1.9.3 dojo with that level of Anywhere.  You should be able to replace the www subdirectory under the MaximoAnywhere project and it should pickup the new dojo, but one warning.  We haven't tested on these later dojo levels, and #2 the dojo files will be much larger and might slow performance down unless you choose to use the compressed ones.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I ran the upgrade on the older version of the Maximo Anywhere, and while in console `dojo.version.toString()` was returning me value 1.7.8. I just created new project from 7.5.2.1, and this shows me version as 1.9.3

Comment: I ran the dojo.version.toString() in console of MobileBrowserSimulator still returns 1.7.8, which means the version that I was previously complaining is actually was of Simulator.